# Show specific data in the highchart's title

Tags: highcharts

I want to show some data in the title of my highchart (i.e. point.total).
I have tried

```
 title: {
                text: 'Project Status Approved,Unapproved and Revised<br/>{value.total}',
            },
```

but it shows {value.total} instead of total data.

Please tell me what to do.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
data.reduce(function (i, a) { return i + a; })
```